# Referencing interface definitions cross projects/repos

Tags: typescript

In a system comprised of multiple TypeScript/node.js services, each in its own repo, we have some shared interface definitions that are used by multiple services/projects. Sometimes they're cyclic. For example, service `foo` needs to invoke objects that implement the `IBar` interface, and the `bar` service needs to invoke `IFoo`. So the question is how to share those interface definitions across repos.

It is my understanding that the best practice for sharing TS code is to actually share the transpiled JS as an NPM package, along with the `.d.ts` files. But I'm not sure creating a cyclic NPM package dependency is such a great idea.

Another option would be to extract the shared interface definitions to one shared repo/package, but that's kind of breaking with the one service = one repo model. Ultimately making it harder and harder to change just one service without worrying about accidentally changing another one.

Are there other options I'm overlooking?